# Mimic a HTTP Observable return with subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have created an angular 4 service that currently uses an HTTP request to return an Observable of type Comment.

```
  return this.http.post(targetUrl, JSON.stringify({ 'Text': comment.Text, 'ThreadId': threadId }), options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

I want this service to return a local data I constructed into a variable when I am on a local host. However, I am unable to just return my local variable of type comment since it is not an Observable. How do I go about making this local variable into an observable?

Comment: [`Observable.of(variable)`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md)?

Comment: That solved my problem but how would I use the Subject class found in the rxjs?

Comment: Why do you think you need to?

Comment: Recommenced by someone more experienced than me with angular 2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in your variable as an argument to Observable.of method.
It will return an observable.

*You can accomplish the same with Subject, but I don't see why you would use one in this scenario.
Anyway,

```
var subject = new Subject();
subject.next(variable);
subject.asObservable();
```

Rx.Observable.of(...args)
Converts arguments to an observable sequence.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md